# Elasticsearch compare fields in an expression

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Ley say I have given these types of document in ES

```
{
    "_source": {
        "field1" : 100,
        "field2" : 200
    }
}
```

What will be the query to find docs which satisfy condition (field1 - fields2 > 50)

```
I tried this
{
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "script": {
        "script": "doc['field1'].value  - doc['field2'].value > 50"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": {
                    "script": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": "doc['field1'].value - doc['field2'].value > 50",
                            "lang": "painless"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure field1 and field2 are numeric type. If not, use Integer.parse to transform.